# LLVM downloads 11 to environment

Tags: virtualenv, llvm, raspberry-pi3, python-3.9, librosa

Best regards
i need to download librosa to raspberry pi so first of all i downloaded virtualenv and created environment and installed llvm with:

```
sudo apt-get install llvm
pip3 install llvmlite==0.37
pip3 install librosa=0.6.3
```

then tried to import a librosa in abc.py file. execution output is:

**importerror-numpy-core-multiarray-failed-to-import**

changing the numpy version didin't help output evolved:
**numba 0.55 requires numpy 1.22**

tried to change numba version but it didin't help either

anyway...

everyone installed llvm version 7 for librosa but my version is 11. I couldn't find the download with version. I've tried:

```
sudo apt-get install llvm-7.0
```

Librosa and numpy does not work well in llvm11.
how can i download version 7?
Thanks for advices

Comment: Which operating system are you running on your RPI?

Comment: raspberry pi OS 32-bit